# elementary OS Freya: Complete freeze including ctrl+f1/f2/f3/f4 etc

Tags: release-freya

Fresh install of elementary OS, if using mouse keyboard to interact no issues.

But when I move away from computer so, no interaction is happening, freya freezes and freezes in the sense that it doesn't even let me use mouse , keyboard or<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> etc.

Same machine when running Ubuntu in similar situations had no such issue.

Could anyone help me or point me in right direction please?